# Лишняя запятая после перечисления

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, что эта запятая здесь лишняя.

Все, кто как-то соприкасается с процессом изобретательства на всех его этапах, от подачи заявки до поставок: изобретатели, патентные поверенные, руководители предприятий и их работники, местные органы власти и самоуправления, правоохранительные, судебные и законодательные органы (лишняя запятая) в части совершенствования законодательства должны соблюдать существующие законы и подзаконные акты по патентному праву, пресекать их нарушения, давая им оценку, исходя из стратегического значения для страны инновационной политики.

Comment: А-а. Я уже поняла. 
Все, кто как-то соприкасается с процессом изобретательства на всех его этапах, от подачи заявки до поставок: изобретатели, патентные поверенные, руководители предприятий и их работники, местные органы власти и самоуправления, правоохранительные, судебные и законодательные органы — в части совершенствования законодательства должны соблюдать существующие законы и подзаконные акты по патентному праву, пресекать их нарушения, давая им оценку, исходя из стратегического значения для страны инновационной политики.

Comment: Запятая, закрывающая уточняющий оборот (на всех этапах, от... до, ...) должна стоять на месте вашего тире (которое обеспечивает выход из конструкции "однородные члены после обобщающего слова"), она его поглощает. Так что изначально, с запятой, было правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Никак не могу понять, почему тут якобы лишняя запятая... Вернее говоря, она есть, но совсем другая - перед "исходя".

Все, *кто как-то соприкасается с процессом изобретательства на всех его этапах, от подачи заявки до поставок: изобретатели, патентные поверенные, руководители предприятий и их работники, местные органы власти и самоуправления, правоохранительные, судебные и законодательные органы,* в части совершенствования законодательства должны соблюдать существующие законы и подзаконные акты по патентному праву, пресекать их нарушения, давая им оценку исходя из стратегического значения для страны инновационной политики.

Курсивом - придаточное, а "исходя" относится к "давая оценку". Это не "деепричастие к деепричастию" (тоже в принципе возможно, хоть и редкость великая), здесь это союз "исходя из", поэтому никаких запятых перед собой не требует.

Comment: А не кажется ли Вам, что более естественный порядок слов таков: "стратегического значения инновационной политики для (нашей) страны"? Я добавил "нашей", чтобы не нарушать ритм фразы.

Answer (score 0):

Советую внести коррективы:
 1. Перед тире надо "закрыть" запятой большое придаточное предложение (кто как-то... и законодательные органы).
 2. Помнится, Розенталь писал, что обороты с предлогами "начиная с", "исходя из" не обособляются. В Вашем предолжении запятая перед "исходя из" создает двусмыслицу, как будто здесь два однородных обстоятельства, выраженных деепричастными оборотами.

Answer (score 0):

Виктор, обороты с предлогом "исходя из" обычно выделяются запятыми. Напр.: ***Исходя из этого,*** ум служит единственно возможным источником наслаждения. ***А. Чехов, Палата № 6.***
Запятые не требуются, если оборот с предлогом "исходя из" тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым.
***Мы по-прежнему пытались прогнозировать своё и общее будущее*** исходя из ***разумных посылок. Е. Гинзбург, Крутой маршрут.*** 
В данном предложении запятая нужна уже потому, что "исходя из" стоит после деепричастного оборота.
[Оборот "исходя из".  Грамота.ру](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=440.8lPyx4jxJTPq-4RGZqBwqKxTUfwn-Yc06q65j3Q6FwAoBSHa-pMmNi6ZmouzUnfIk1fCfObsrAQ9L0HJ8CHN4OIQUn7ALPLSyMKP8JqDAhMKKCTUua4mjWwuY6dzXgd13JfPk9V2swTyEmf_M6MBuzfo9SaUcqje6yvkVeC42R8.c3fd3f14aa952fc614f8a4509d2b4cbf49bcf3fe&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfy1qNK6_no62JEFvW2UZjThC5Cf5S_aZ5NHu-SKvak3zgygmnPg4NBqnV-HLHUXhePqR1MuFNtD-ZyGi2gJxs0LFcYehmDLccowj20FVjg2uKe6mKYv6n2w22HERKCxUDhUCFrvMC6LU9Ce3gsWIsOxle3gm9Kb1zpZ9QY7k2fONwnsB5R5UAfA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRDTTdORUZYeDB1Y3paMmRiWVdaNTVNVk13QlhXaFBOY1pGSDVkWndEZllLQ0tDUks4WFFhZ3VnVlJVbWR2alJDY0Q4M2hmZ3BTVXMyci1yRjV1Z1BfNA&b64e=2&sign=ee154cb9ddfbe34ec8b23dce248a7293&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1410118152816&mc=4.123645696227706)

Comment: Именно об этом я и писал, дорогой Серж, что возникает искажение смысла, как будто здесь два деепричастных оборота. Предлог "исходя из" здесь может быть изъят без нарушения смысла фразы

Comment: Давая им оценку  стратегического значения. Вы предлагаете такой вариант( если изъять оборот "исходя из")? Я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: Примерно так.

Answer (score 0):

"...пресекать их нарушения, давая им оценку исходя из стратегического значения для страны инновационной политики".

Запятая действительно не нужна, так как в составе деепричастного оборота обстоятельственный оборот имеет сильное управление (не допускается пауза). Это общее правило для подобных структур (один оборот внутри другого оборота).

А вообще, оборот с этим предлогом  обычно не обособляется, но есть два исключения: 1) уточнение; 2) значение действия, выраженное глаголом "исходить":

График построен исходя из экспериментальных данных.

Влияние всех факторов учтено реально, исходя из данных эксперимента.

Лётчики могут менять строй самолётов, исходя из конкретной обстановки.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Предлагается оставить следующий вариант:

Все,  кто как-то соприкасается с процессом изобретательства на всех его этапах, от подачи заявки до поставок: изобретатели, патентные поверенные, руководители предприятий и их работники, местные органы власти и самоуправления, правоохранительные, судебные и законодательные органы  – в части совершенствования законодательства должны соблюдать существующие законы и подзаконные акты по патентному праву, пресекать их нарушения, 
давая им оценку исходя из стратегического значения для страны инновационной политики.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Обобщающее слово распространено придаточным предложением, вторая запятая поглощается тире. Похожий пример: "Всё, что могло приглушить звуки: ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель, – Григ давно убрал из дома".

Comment: Не обособляется, если тесно связан со сказуемым.
___

А так, Виктор прав: лучше изъять оборот "исходя из".